# unable to click button with unique button data-order-group-id 's information python+selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

javascript code (repeat order 1):

```
<div class="col-ea-1 repeat-order repeatable-order">  #common row in other snippets
 <button data-order-group-id="a9755447-04ff-4d00-59bf-06ff87f8ead6" #different row 
 data-restaurant-seo-url="/abc-pizza-bayburt-kirazli-mah" 
 class="ys-btn ys-btn-primary ys-btn-aa middle repeat-order-button"> REPEAT ORDER </button> ==$0
</div>
```

In the above snippet javascript code, there is more than one for each order (button data-order-group-id is different for each order) I also want to reach and click the REPEAT ORDER button for each order How can I do this in this piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the below xpath :

```
//button[contains(text(), 'REPEAT ORDER') and contains(@class, 'repeat-order-button')]
```

using `find_element` for single row, and `find_elements` for multiple row.

**sample code :**

```
for ele in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'REPEAT ORDER') and contains(@class, 'repeat-order-button')]"):
    ele.click()
    # do some other stuff
    # re-initiate elements here otherwise you will get stale element reference
    #break if requires
```

Comment: It gives an error like this when it passes to the second element in the for loop: ElementClickInterceptedException  ...class="ys-btn ys-btn-primary ys-btn-aa middle repeat-order-button">...</button> is not clickable at point (1075, 598). Other element would receive the click: <div id="ys-ls-chat-initializer" class="online">...</div>  ,actually the help center is fixed in the corner on the site, I don't understand why it affects the code

Answer (score 0):

@cruisepandey your code is working well but due to
the website's specific conditions which are help center fixed box and ORDER REPEAT buttons can overlap somehow That's why I used "window.scrollTo" before in addition to your code

```
i=int(input("choose:"))
   
if i==0:
                  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300)") #move the area 
                  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'REPEAT ORDER') and contains(@class, 'repeat-order-button')]")[0].click()
                  sleep(7)
elif i==1:      
                  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300)") #move the area 
                  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'REPEAT ORDER') and contains(@class, 'repeat-order-button')]")[1].click()
                  sleep(7)
elif i==2:
                  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 600)") #move the area   
                  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'REPEAT ORDER') and contains(@class, 'repeat-order-button')]")[2].click()
                  sleep(7)
```